# Prompt a user once from a recursive function only ONCE

Tags: c#, recursion

So I have a function I simplified here that asks the user if they want to continue (with the recursion). If they say yes, the function continues and calls itself no problem. But then it asks again... and again... It asks every time it calls. I want to ask only once. Is there any way to ask from within the function, or is it absolutely necessary to put it outside?

```
void RFunction()
{
    bool proceed = true;
    if (proceed && other tests)
    {
        // We have to ask here because we only ask if (other tests)
        proceed = AskUser();
        RFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to ask only once and, if the user confirms, continue until stack runs out?

Comment: Oh, i guess that `other tests` will eventually return `false` to exit the recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An often use technique to pass state variables down the recursion stack is through optional parameters.
In your example it would be:

```
void RFunction(bool proceed = false)
{
    if (proceed && other tests)
    {
        // We have to ask here because we only ask if (other tests)
        proceed = AskUser();
        RFunction(proceed);
    }
}
```

Now when you call it with

```
RFunction();
```

It will start with `proceed` set to false, and later on overwrite the value with whatever `AskUser()` returned.

Also note that the way your code is currently structured, initializing it to false doesn't make much sense as it will never reach the recursive call. This might be what you're looking for:

```
void RFunction(bool? proceed = null)
{
    if ( !proceed.HasValue ) {
        proceed = AskUser();
    }

    if (proceed.Value && other tests)
    {
        RFunction(proceed);
    }
}
```

I opted for nullable bool since the other answer includes a solution with a state counter. Now `null` means "I don't know, ask the user", and true/false mean do/don't proceed.

Comment: In your first example, if `proceed` starts out as false, how would it ever get changed? You won't enter the `if` block.

Comment: (well not really, just added a note, since that snipped is based on the OP)

Comment: Very nice. Never even heard of nullable bools before.

Answer (score 0):

I would factor the call that you have 3 states (wrote this without a compiler on hand):

```
void RFunction(int aProceed = 0)
{


    if (aProceed >= 0 && other tests)
    {
      if (aProceed == 0)
         if (AskUser())          
           aProceed++;
        else
           aProceed--;
        // We have to ask here because we only ask if (other tests)           
        RFunction(aProceed);
    }
}
```

There are variations, but this should do it.

Comment: fixed the missing "a"

Comment: I neglected to add, you could have "aProceed" continually increment each call if you want to also track how deep your stack goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in with another example, you can add a parameter to the method to indicate if you should prompt the user first. If it's set to true, then ask the user if we should proceed. Otherwise it appears that you want to proceed every time

Presumably `otherTests` will at some point exit the recursion. Since you only want to prompt the user when `otherTests` pass, then just put that check first in the `if` condition. That way, if the tests fail, the condition evaluates to `false` right away and the rest of the condition is not checked.

Notice that I have combined `(!askUser || AskUser())` in the `if` condition. This means that it will be `true` if `askUser` is `false`; otherwise, if `askUser` is `true`, then it will be `true` if `AskUser()` returns `true`.

So the order of conditions will be:

1. If otherTests fail, do nothing and exit the function
2. Otherwise (if the tests passed), if `askUser` is `false` then execute the recursive call in the `if` block
3. Otherwise (if `askUser` is true) then call the `AskUser` method, and if it returns `true`, then execute the recursive call in the `if` block
4. Otherwise (if `AskUser` returns `false`), do nothing and exit the function

This is simpler than some of the other 3-state solutions, though the syntax may take some getting used to?

```
void RFunction(bool askUser = true)
{
    if (otherTests && (!askUser || AskUser()))
    {
        RFunction(false);
    }
}
```